# Passing "return false" between functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the title is a bad title, I don't know any way to explain this other than with an example:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $(this).find('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('error'))
      return false;
  });
});
```

However, the "return false" is returning the ".each()" with false. How can I "pass" it onto the ".submit()"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for any input in that form that has the class error, you could do:

```
return $(this).find('input.error').length == 0;
```

Comment: Meh, your version is easier to approach logically, mine has inversion, if there is a class that returns true so you would have to invert it to return false as he desires. +1 for a more straightforward approach. =P

Comment: @MatthewCox - Using `hasClass` would've been cleaner if it wasn't for the inversion. If jQuery had a boolean way to check if any element matched the selector, that would be the cleanest, like a shortcut for checking length. `$(this).any('input.error')`.

Answer (score 2):

Just simplify it. It appears that if you find one instance of this class you want to return false, which can be done like so:

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    return $(this).find('input').hasClass('error') == false;
});
```

You could also use a NOT operator but that just looks ugly with selectors IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.each()` method calls a callback function you can't return from the submit from inside the `.each()` callback.  So, you have to set a variable for your return value and then return that later.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var retVal = true;
  $(this).find('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('error'))
      retVal = false;
      return false;
  });
  return(retVal);
});
```

You could also solve this problem by letting the selector engine do your searching rather than iterating yourself with `.each()` like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  if ($(this).find('input.error').length != 0) {
      return(false);
  }
});
```

or a little more succinctly:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
      return($(this).find('input.error').length == 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a varaible outside the loop, and set before exiting the loop, then return the value of the variable:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var result = true;
  $(this).find('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('error'))
      result = false;
      return false; // exit loop
  });
  return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var allok = true;
  $(this).find('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('error'))
      allok  =false;
  });
  return allok;
});
```